# How to source additional file when launching bash

Tags: bash

Bash will source automatic profiles such as `.bashrc`. `--rcfile` option can be used to override the automatic script. But I need to source *additional* personalized file (that's the automatic script plus another file) when launching the bash shell **without touching ANY files in `$HOME` or `/etc` directory** since `$HOME` directory belongs to application run user. The personalized file must not be located in `$HOME` directory.
Is this possible?

I tried:

```
    /bin/bash <<EOF
    . /a-directory-outside-of-home/vanilla
    EOF
```

but it returned to the current shell.

Comment: Can you source the extra file from within your .bashrc?

Comment: that's not a option. I want to source another script without touching the .bashrc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so you want to run the user's normal `.bashrc`, followed by your own script, and you want to trigger this behavior in the way that `bash` is called, correct?

The call:

```
/bin/bash --rcfile myscript
```

First line of `myscript`:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bash --rcfile <(cat rcfile1; cat rcfile2)
```

works just fine and requires no modifications anywhere.

Comment: Nice to enter a python virtualenv in one step. Btw. you don’t need the `;` as cat concatenates all inputs by default. `bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc env/bin/activate)`

Comment: Or as a handy function to add to your .bash_aliases: `enterVE(){ [[ -n $1 && -a "$1/bin/activate" ]] && bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.bashrc $1/bin/activate) || echo 'No virtual environment path given as parameter'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Add your stuff as *.sh files in `/etc/profile.d` -- read `/etc/profile` and 
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Also, one cannot assume that the user has root access to modify /etc

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't modify the `.bashrc` file. Instead, I would modify the `.bash_profile`
file which is located at `$HOME`.

It is the place from where .bashrc is included.

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/bashrc
fi
```

A good option for you is to add a `.personalized_settings` file and include it
just below the above lines like this.

```
# Adding personalized settings
if [ -f ~/.personalized_settings ]; then
  . ~/personalized_settings
fi
```

This requires that `.personalized_settings` file is located at `$HOME`.

I have tested the above in Fedora12.

**Edit** :
You might need to look for `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile` in Ubuntu (and hopefully other Debian based systems).  (courtesy @Benjamin W.)

This (link)[https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files] will give you more information on it.

**What if you mess around with any of the profile files?**

You have a back-up copy of all these files in `/etc/skel` which you could
use to restore.

Comment: It's called `.profile` in Ubuntu, see for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/510709/i-can-not-find-bash-profile-in-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for that info.. It's difficult in that these names are not standard.. Redhat and it clones have one way of doing it, Debian based system has another..

Comment: The order in which Bash tries to find them is specified, though: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files